# SSRS XML decimal format does not match web format

Tags: xml, reporting-services

How do I control the decimal format when exporting a SSRS report to XML?

I have the Format property of my cells set to 0.0. The values display correctly in when run in BDS, in web viewer, and in PDF.  However, when I export to XML the precision is lost.  For instance; it shows as 13.4 in PDF, but 13.37 in XML. Of course this causes issues when imported into other systems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the **Format** property, this doesn't actually change the underlying value when you export to Excel and XML.

Take this simple report.

Dataset:

[image]

Output:

[image]

This exports to XML as:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <Report xsi:schemaLocation="Report1 http://reportserver/?%2fReport1&rs%3aFormat=XML&rc%3aSchema=True" Name="Report1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Report1">
  <Tablix1>
  <Details_Collection>
  <Details MyValue1="1.234" MyValue2="1.2" /> 
  <Details MyValue1="5.678" MyValue2="5.7" /> 
  </Details_Collection>
  </Tablix1>
  </Report>
```

What's the difference here?

The first value is controlled with the **Format** property, but the second is actually an expression in the textbox:

```
=Format(Fields!MyValue2.Value, "N1")
```

So, the **Format** property controls how the value is displayed but doesn't change its type, but an explicit `Format` expression returns a string so the XML export is unaware of any more detail other than the final result.

The PDF export will be identical for both columns but the XML export treats them differently as you see. The second option, i.e. a `Format` expression, might work in your case.

Comment: Dude, sooo awesome. I thought those two formatting options did the same thing.  And you explanation of 'why' is super helpful.

Comment: No problem! It's something that I've seen for Excel exports, but I figured I'd see if it was the same principle for XML; turns it it's the same issue. Cool!